# Get node text inside filled region in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have made this figure

[image]

from this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-90:200, x=0.025cm, y=0.15cm]

\draw[->,very thick] (-100,0) -- (250,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (0,45) node[above] {$y$};

\foreach \x in {-4,...,10} {
    \draw (20*\x,0) -- (20*\x,-1);
}
\foreach \y in {0,...,45} {
    \draw (0,\y) -- (-1,\y);
}

\draw[color=blue] plot ({\x},{34}) node[right] {$MR = 34$};
\draw[color=red] plot ({\x},{0.0018*\x*\x-0.2*\x+10}) node[above] {$MC = 0.0018 Q^2-0.2 Q + 10$};

\fill[pattern color=green, pattern=north east lines, opacity=0.9] plot[domain=-72.5840284:183.69514] ({\x},{0.0018*\x*\x-0.2*\x+10}) -- plot ({\x},{34}) -- cycle node {$DB$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How is it possible to get the node with text `DB` inside the filled region? If I use `node[midway]` it will be above the middle of the blue line but I want it exactly in the middle of the filled green region.

Comment: Something like `\node[fill=white] at (55,25) {DB};`? Did you considered to use [`pgfplots` ](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/tag/functions/) for this kind of graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `path picture` like

```
\fill[pattern color=green, pattern=north east lines, opacity=0.9,path picture={
            \node[anchor=south]  at (path picture bounding box.center) {DB};
          }] plot[domain=-72.5840284:183.69514] ({\x},{0.0018*\x*\x-0.2*\x+10}) -- plot ({\x},{34}) -- cycle;
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-90:200, x=0.025cm, y=0.15cm]

\draw[->,very thick] (-100,0) -- (250,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (0,45) node[above] {$y$};

\foreach \x in {-4,...,10} {
    \draw (20*\x,0) -- (20*\x,-1);
}
\foreach \y in {0,...,45} {
    \draw (0,\y) -- (-1,\y);
}

\draw[color=blue] plot ({\x},{34}) node[right] {$MR = 34$};
\draw[color=red] plot ({\x},{0.0018*\x*\x-0.2*\x+10}) node[above] {$MC = 0.0018 Q^2-0.2 Q + 10$};

\fill[pattern color=green, pattern=north east lines, opacity=0.9,path picture={
            \node[anchor=south]  at (path picture bounding box.center) {DB};
          }] plot[domain=-72.5840284:183.69514] ({\x},{0.0018*\x*\x-0.2*\x+10}) -- plot ({\x},{34}) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is better to use `pgfplots` for your plotting needs though.

Comment: If I use `pgfplots`, is it still good to use `path picture`?

Comment: @Jamgreen You can as plots are just `\path`s.